# Uploading failed, please try agin

Tags: php, sql, alert

When I click on "Add Country", localhost says : Uploading failed, please try again.
Can you tell me where is the mistake please ?

```
<?php

    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'db');

    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $c_code = addslashes($_POST["c_code"]);
        $c_name = addslashes($_POST["c_name"]);
        $c_key = addslashes($_POST["c_key"]);
        {
          $sql = "insert into countries(country_code, country_name, country_key) values('$c_code', '$c_name', '$c_key')";

          $rs = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

          if($rs)
          {
            echo "<script> alert('Country uploaded successfully') </script>";
          }

          else

          {
            echo "<script> alert('Uploading failed, please try again.') </script>";
          } 
        }
    }


?>
```

Comment: your query failed; check for errors

Comment: http://codular.com/php-mysqli

Comment: Try adding this to your query
`$rs = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));`

Comment: Probably because you're looking for `mysqli_connect()` instead of `new mysqli()`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge it's valid.

Comment: Sweet. Didn't realise you could mix procedural and OOP.

Comment: @ObsidianAge yeah, it's not recommended but it does work.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Didn't you used to post sql injection warnings? :P

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton constantly at first, then my fingers cramped up.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Do you use the copy-paste method? I've been looking for your post so I can copy it because I like the wording and the links you used, but I can't find a comment with your message :P

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I used to keep one, but TBH I lost its whereabouts for it. Maybe it'll surface when I'm not looking for something; isn't that how it always happens? *lol!*

Comment: @Kevin P. When I used $rs = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($db)); I've this Unknown column 'country_code' in 'field list'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'db');

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $c_code = addslashes($_POST["c_code"]);
    $c_name = addslashes($_POST["c_name"]);
    $c_key = addslashes($_POST["c_key"]);

   //remove this:"{" 

      $sql = "insert into countries(country_code, country_name, country_key) values('$c_code', '$c_name', '$c_key')";

      $rs = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

      if($rs)
      {
        echo "<script> alert('Country uploaded successfully') </script>";
      }

      else

      {
        echo ("Error here:" .mysqli_error($db));
      } 
    }
  //also remove this: "}"
```

Comment: Please mention the modification done by you in this code.

Comment: I just removed the `{`, added a comment in the code and changed the `echo` to know what the error is @NanaPartykar

Comment: @Peter Partykar Uploading failed, please try again.Unknown column 'country_code' in 'field list'

Comment: did you create `country_code` column in your table? @nouamane18

Comment: Peter Haddad hit it right on the money.

Comment: @Peter Haddad -  Thank you Peter

Comment: @nouamane18 no problem :) glad I could help.